# Mysql combine link with title

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 fields in a mysql database.  They are title which is the news article title and (description/link) which is the link to the article. The web page is http://vince.netau.net .Type bitcoin in the search field.  I would like to be able to click on the title and bring up the link to the article. I don't want to even see the description column with the link like it is currently.

Here is the code I have currently which has the Title with the link but I'm showing the link in the next column which I don't want.  Also, is there a way to not have the title underlined?

```
 <td><a href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>"
        <td><?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></td>
```

Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: You should use CSS to remove the underline, or you can use this : <a href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">

Comment: _"Also, is there a way to not have the title underlined?"_ - research is not that hard, try it. https://www.google.com/search?q=link+not+underlined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not close tags correctly. Try this, they will be in same column

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></a></td>
```

I hope this helps

Edit:

Also for not underlined link you can use this css attribute:

```
<td><a style="text-decoration: none;" href="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html code is not really correct. You have to close all tags and you should read about HTML and the HTML structure.

```
<td>
    <a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Anyone know how to stop the headings from repeating after every entry at http://vince.netau.net   I just want title and data 1 time at the top. Search for Bitcoin.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `link` instead of `description`.
Using css you can remove the underline:

```
<td>
    <a href="<?php echo $row['link']; ?>" style="text-decoration: none;">
        <?php echo $row['post_title']; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```